# Hibernate search on multi fields

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, hibernate-search

I would like to do a fulltext search on an entity.

It works when I'm using a single keyword but no more.

```
        Query luceneQuery = qb
        .keyword()
        .wildcard()
        .onFields("description", "brand" )
        .matching("*" + searchTerm + "*").createQuery();
```

In one case I have a entity with a description equal "car" and brand equal "ford"

The search returns the expected result if the query is "car" or "ford" but not for "car ford"

Any ideas ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query = qb.bool()
            .should( qb.keyword().fuzzy().onField("description").ignoreFieldBridge().matching(searchTerm).createQuery() )
            .should( qb.keyword().fuzzy().onField("color").ignoreFieldBridge().matching(searchTerm).createQuery() )
            .should(qb.keyword().fuzzy().onField("brand").matching(searchTerm).createQuery() )
            .createQuery();
```